# Specify first row in select statement then sort the rest alphabetically

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am working on a project and I have this query

```
SELECT [Categories_Name]
FROM [Categories]
ORDER BY CASE [Categories_Name] WHEN 'Select' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

What I want is that to make to top row in the result to be 'Select' and the rest rows are sorted alphabetically

The query that I have makes to first row Select but the rest is not sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two keys in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT Categories_Name
FROM Categories
ORDER BY (CASE Categories_Name WHEN 'Select' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         Categories_Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT [Categories_Name]
FROM [Categories]
ORDER BY CASE [Categories_Name] WHEN 'Select' THEN '1' ELSE Categories_Name END
```

Comment: This could produce undesired results, depending on the actual values in `Categories_Name` and the collation being applied, though.

Comment: OP wanted the output to be sorted alphabetically, not alpha numerically, so in that case the output would be just fine. Otherwise you are right